# Sending signal to a bash while loop in screen

Tags: bash, signals

I have a `screen` process which is using an infinite bash loop to run a PHP script indefinitely:

```
screen -S proc1 -d -m bash -c while [ true ] ; do /path/to/application.php ; done
```

I would like to gracefully stop the bash loop, such that the current PHP process finishes running but no more processes are started.

If I send a signal (using `kill` or `killall`) will it be caught by screen, or the bash loop, or the PHP script?

Comment: it depends the PID you will send the signal to. PHP, bash and screen processes will have different PIDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Write a signal handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) into your PHP script to do its thing when it receives the signal from `kill` or `killall`.

```
function sig_handler($signo) {
    switch ($signo) {
        case SIGTERM:
            // handle shutdown tasks
            exit;
    }
}
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, "sig_handler");
```

Sending the signal to the `php` PID will definitely do the job. If you send to the `screen` PID, not sure how it would work. Probably `screen` would kill it processes off nicely but I don't know.

Edit: apparently you can't write a handler for `SIGKILL` so stick with `SIGTERM` (just calling `kill 12345` sends `SIGTERM` while `kill -9 12345` sends `SIGKILL`)